# Exception in import ADT Plugin in windows 7 32bit

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, adt

When I try to import the ADT plugin in my eclipse for android, I am getting following exception

> An Error Occurred while downloading
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.jar The cache file
>   C:\Program
>   Files\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\downloading\content472334498.jar
>   could not be renamed to C:\Program
>   Files\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\downloading\content472334498.jar.
>
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProviionException

OS is window7 32bit

Thanks

M. Prabhu

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Android Studio instead, it is created by Google and is much better than eclipse with a android plugin.